# Can you use more than one monitor with NVidia SLI?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, sli

I have not explored NVidia SLI in a while, but I remember it being impossible to use more than one monitor in SLI mode.  Is this still true or has the support for this gotten better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SLI has multi-monitor support now since the GeForce 180 driver. Although it is not possible to use multiple monitors in fullscreen 3D mode.

[Here](http://www.slizone.com/object/sli_multi_monitor.html) is more information about the feature.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method for getting dual monitors to work if you have a third graphics card to plug the secondary monitor into. You can find info about this [here](http://techtipdaily.com/2008/07/29/dual-monitors-with-sli/) and [here](http://www.tech-forums.net/pc/f78/sli-dual-monitors-works-168567/). This is an older method that may not be necessary any more.

Late last year, Nvidia released new 180-series drivers where [there is better support](http://multimonitor.net/2008/11/multiple-monitors-with-nvidias-geforce-180-driver/) for multi-monitor modes. It looks like you can simply plug your other monitor into the secondary port on your primary graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple monitors on your SLI cards, OR you can run them in SLI mode. It's a simple software change in the NVidia control applet, but no you can't do both at once.  Putting the SLI'd output across multiple RAMDACs would nullify the benefit in SLI.

Having said that, if you find the right board, you could theoretically run two in SLI and a third card with multiple outputs.

Comment: Does the software change require a reboot?  I remember that being the case way back when.

Comment: Depends on how your hardware is configured. If you have the hardware bridge between the cards you should be fine without a reboot. Only way to know for sure is to try it.